# Import defaultMember vs Member javascript

Tags: javascript, import

I'm learning React and am not familiar with import and exporting. Looking at the docs, they don't really explain what a defaultMember is - what is the difference between between `React` and `{ Component, PropTypes }`? Isn't `{Component, PropTypes` part of `React` which will get imported already just from `React`?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with React and everything to do with the [`import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: @zzzzBov that's why i tagged it javascript and import??